# swift 4 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate instead of actual date string after JSONSerialization

Tags: json, alamofire, swift4, datetimepicker

i have an object which i set the value of date like this

```
notificToSubmit.NotificDateCreated = Date()
notificToSubmit.NotificOccDateTime = dtPicker.date
```

Now I want to send my object to my api using ALAMO fire. I need to convert it to JSONObject. Which would look something like this:

```
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(notifToSubmit)
let jsonD = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
```

All is good but its giving me the wrong date value.
It gives me the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate instead of the actual date value:

```
(2 elements)
  - key: NotificDateCreated #1
    - super: NSMutableString
      - super: NSString
        - super: NSObject
  - value: 552834752.59258 #2
    - super: NSNumber
      - super: NSValue
        - super: NSObject
```

instead of

```
NotificDateCreated: 2018-07-09 13:12:32 +0000
NotificOccuredDateTime: 2018-07-09 13:12:28 +0000
```

and yes I know, that the number which is **552834752.59258** is a valid date valid, but the API doesnt recognize it.

Any Ideas how I can get the actual date which is **2018-07-09 13:12:32** after JSONSerialization

Comment: `JSONEncoder` encodes `Date` instances to `Int`, `Double` or `String` depending on the date strategy because JSON does not support `Date`. What type does the API expect?

Comment: hello @vadian it is expecting a date format by string type. You are right, JSONEncoder has that limitation, so I needed to convert all my date properties to string, and create a function to do .toString and toDate. it is working now, thank you

Comment: The JSON format *has that limitation*, not `JSONEncoder`. I wrote an answer suggesting a smart solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a string representation of a date you can pass a custom date encoding strategy to the encoder for example

```
struct Foo : Codable {
    let date : Date
}

let foo = Foo(date: Date())

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
do {
    let data = try encoder.encode(foo)
    print(String(data: data, encoding:.utf8)!) // {"date":"2018-07-10 10:44:16"}
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here for the Google Code Warriors - **Alamofire 5**:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = JSONEncoder.DateEncodingStrategy.iso8601
AF.request(api, method: httpMethod, parameters: encodableRequestData, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.init(encoder: encoder))
```

This will encode any Date fields in your encodableRequestData to iso8601 strings.  You can choose other DateEncodingStrategies as well or make your own

Comment: Warrior approved! This works great for using a Date object and sending data up to a Node.js / MongoDB implementation with the createdAt, updatedAt date fields. Thank you! I'm surprised this solution isn't widely adopted b/c not much is out there for Date mappings encoding/decoding with AF.